# Visual Studio 2012 Linq to SQL visualizer

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

What's the easiest way to see the SQL (and ideally data) produced by a Linq query in Visual Studio 2012?. I have previously used a number of debug visualizers that work well in VS2008/2010 but I can't seem to find a working one for 2012.

For example say I have the Linq:

```
var l = ctx.PurchaseOrders.Where(c => c.PurchaseOrderID == searchstring);
```

How do i see what SQL is that Linq is being converted to?

i am using Entity Framework

Comment: Are you using Linq2SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: For the SQL, you can just evaluate `query.ToString()` (`DbContext`) or `query.ToTraceString()` (`ObjectContext`), for example in the quick watch window. But I'm not sure for the data.

Comment: I'd take the `ToTraceString()` output, like @hvd suggests and run it in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being stupid, say I have the linq: var l = ctx.PurchaseOrders.Where(c => c.PurchaseOrderID == searchstring); how do i evaluate l? using l.ToString();

Comment: Yes, `l.ToString()` should work. Also, you can do `((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)l).ToTraceString()`

Comment: I was using the Linq to Entity query visualizer by RRV, but I am yet to get it to work in VS2012...

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [Orm profiler](http://www.ormprofiler.com/), It's not free, but it saves me a lot of time to view view SQL generated by EF and analyze performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `Visual Studio IntelliTrace`.

Answer (score 0):

If you run against MS SQL Server you can use the "SQL Server Profiler". Besides the SQL statement including the parameters you get statistical information for your query (CPU costs, reads, writes, ...).